# How real-time chat is possible on a multi-server infrastructure?

Tags: facebook, chat, real-time

Take Facebook for example: they have tons of servers. Now lets say that Alice goes on Facebook and the FB Load Balancer sends her to Server A. After a while, Bob goes on FB and the Load Balancer sends him to Server B. Alice and Bob begin to chat. Now, how the instant message travels across the servers? I'm not interested about browser web-page update (it is quite easy with AJAX, HTTP Long-Pooling, etc.). I would like to know how the things work server-side. 
When Alice writes a message, how can Server A instantly notify Server B about the new action?

Comment: most probably, when they start chat, there's information about which server other side uses at that specific moment. So Bob's side knows to look at Server A for chat updates from Alice and vice versa, Alice's side knows to look at Server B for Bob's messages.

Comment: But this would require almost each server connected to each other. I think it's quite a big overload.

Comment: no, just for that reason, to avoid looking at "thousands" of servers , there's probably some kind of user-index table to keep data about what server each user uses. So when chat session starts, scripts can easily get right server to look at. this is just blind guess and possibility.

Comment: so, for example, Bob gets data from `https://server-a/user_alice/chat` and Alice from `https://server-b/user_bob/chat`. course it probably uses user-id to identify user, not their actual names.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to ask Mark to be sure.

But the best guesses would be related to how you personally would implement it.

I might do something along the lines of Wh1T3h4Ck5's comment, something like a look up table, which would be a bit hard to keep consistent, or a query to some central authority that simply knows which server a particular user is attached to. That might not work out if a user is connected to many servers (on mobile, tablet and computer all at the same time).

I personally have implemented an service where a messages sent get pushed onto a particular user's stack, but that required each client to check on a timer if there were new messages on the stack.